# Automatic cropping image using OpenCV not working properly

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, crop

[Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPNj7.jpg) , [Output Cropped properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhp5G.jpg), [Input Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txa6c.jpg), [Output not cropped properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOZGW.jpg) We are performing Auto Crop operations using OpenCV library in C# project, For few sample automatically cropping the image but for other samples It was not cropping properly.

Let us know anything is missing in source code.

Please find the below piece of code.

```
        Mat image = new Mat();
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        Nullable<bool> result = openFileDlg.ShowDialog();
        if (result == true)
        {
            image = Cv2.ImRead(openFileDlg.FileName);
        }
        
        Mat GrayImage = new Mat();
        Cv2.CvtColor(image, GrayImage, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);

        Mat BlurImage = new Mat();
        Cv2.GaussianBlur(GrayImage,BlurImage, new OpenCvSharp.Size(5,5),0);

        Mat CannyImage = new Mat();
        OpenCvSharp.Point[][] contours;
        HierarchyIndex[] hierarchy;
        Cv2.Canny(BlurImage, CannyImage, 80, 150,7);

        Cv2.ImShow("Original Image", image);
        Cv2.ImShow("Canny Edged Image", CannyImage);
        Cv2.DestroyAllWindows();
       
        Cv2.FindContours(CannyImage, out contours, out hierarchy,RetrievalModes.External, ContourApproximationModes.ApproxSimple);

        image.SaveImage(@"C:\Users\TestAccount\Documents\AutoCrop_OpenCV\Output03012022\20220103.jpeg");

        var contourIndex = 0;
        var previousArea = 0;
        var biggestContourRect = Cv2.BoundingRect(contours[0]);
        while ((contourIndex >= 0))
        {
            var contour = contours[contourIndex];

            var boundingRect = Cv2.BoundingRect(contour); //Find bounding rect for each contour
            var boundingRectArea = boundingRect.Width * boundingRect.Height;
            if (boundingRectArea > previousArea)
            {
                biggestContourRect = boundingRect;
                previousArea = boundingRectArea;
            }
            
            contourIndex = hierarchy[contourIndex].Next;
        }
        

        var finalImage = new Mat(image, biggestContourRect); //Crop the image
        string outputBaseDirectory = @"C:\Users\TestAccount\Documents\AutoCrop_OpenCV\Output03012022";
        finalImage.SaveImage(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", outputBaseDirectory, "\\Output", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDlg.FileName)));
        Cv2.ImShow("Final Image", finalImage);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what exactly you mean under a `cropped properly` and `not cropped properly` ? Samples of input and output for both cases will be also helpful to understand the problem.

Comment: hi serg,

Cropped properly means - removing unwanted borders from images and detected edges correct.

Not Cropped properly - Unwanted borders are not removed and size of the images is not incorrect.

Comment: Updated Input image and output images for references.

Comment: "it doesn't work, please fix" is way below what's expected of someone asking a question on this site. please review the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV requires a better contrast than is shown with the latter incorrect crop. Try using a threshold function before trying to find the contours. The main issue I see with the incorrect crop though is the the background can be partially seen through the paper and this will prevent proper detection of the edges.

**In short** - the contrast needs to be improved, this can be done with thresholding.

**Edit**

```
/// <summary>
        /// Performs a gradient detection function and returns the altered image
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mat">The Mat image to perform the functions on</param>
        /// <param name="id">ID for tests</param>
        /// <returns>The Mat image altered by the function</returns>
        public static Mat GradientDetection(Mat mat, string id = "")
        {
            Log.Information("Performing gradient detection on image");
            Mat clone = mat.Sobel(MatType.CV_32F, 1, 0);
            if (_settingsService.PIDSettings.Detector.SetTestRemoveBorder != 0)
            {
                SaveLoadHelper.SaveImage(clone, $"{id}_Sobel");
            }
            clone = clone.Abs();
            if (_settingsService.PIDSettings.Detector.SetTestRemoveBorder != 0)
            {
                SaveLoadHelper.SaveImage(clone, $"{id}_GradientDetection");
            }
            clone.MinMaxIdx(out double min, out double max);
            clone = 255 * ((clone - min) / (max - min));
            if (_settingsService.PIDSettings.Detector.SetTestRemoveBorder != 0)
            {
                SaveLoadHelper.SaveImage(clone, $"{id}_ScaledBack");
            }
            return clone;
        }
```

and

```
/// <summary>
         /// Detects lines in the image then return a mask of detected areas
         /// </summary>
         /// <param name="mat">The Mat image to run the detection on</param>
         /// <param name="rectKernel">Rectangular Kernel</param>
         /// <param name="squareKernel">Square Kernel</param>
         /// <param name="threshold">Theshold for image binarisation</param>
         /// <param name="id">ID for tests</param>
         /// <returns>The Mat image with the detections performed on it</returns>
        public static Mat LineDetection(Mat mat, Mat rectKernel, Mat squareKernel, int threshold = 65, string id = "")
        {
            Log.Information("Performing Line detection on image");

            mat = mat.MorphologyEx(MorphTypes.Close, rectKernel);
            if (_settingsService.PIDSettings.Detector.SetTestRemoveBorder != 0)
            {
                SaveLoadHelper.SaveImage(mat, $"{id}_LineDetectionStage1");
            }
            mat.ConvertTo(mat, MatType.CV_8UC1);
            mat = mat.Threshold(threshold, 255, ThresholdTypes.Binary);
            if (_settingsService.PIDSettings.Detector.SetTestRemoveBorder != 0)
            {
                SaveLoadHelper.SaveImage(mat, $"{id}_LineDetectionStage2");
            }
            mat = mat.MorphologyEx(MorphTypes.Close, squareKernel);
            //mat = mat.Erode(InputArray.KIND_SHIFT, null, 4);
            mat = mat.Erode(InputArray.KIND_SHIFT, null, 2);
            if (_settingsService.PIDSettings.Detector.SetTestRemoveBorder != 0)
            {
                SaveLoadHelper.SaveImage(mat, $"{id}_LineDetectionStage3");
            }
            return mat;
        }
```

Helped quite a bit here

Comment: Thanks Lloys.

Please let me know is there any built in method to detect input image has low contrast. We have checked that, there are no built in methods in OpencvSharp.

Comment: I have added a Edit to my answer. I hope this helps a bit.